# google analytic appends a bunch of GA info after the URL

Tags: url, google-analytics, hyperlink, cross-domain

I have a simple link wrapped around a logo which links to another website and from that website another logo which links back to the previous site , but it seems that google analytics is appending all sort of info after the url/

first ?_ga=2.52031145.1021203784.1684750132-1465375511.1661873906
and back ?
_gl=1*12trja9*_ga*MTQ2NTM3NTUxMS4xNjYxODczOTA2*_ga_13LR68QH50*MTY4NDc0OTg5OS4xNjkuMS4xNjg0NzUzMzEyLjI2LjAuMA..

what is this about ? how do I remove it ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should provide more info about what have you done and where are you observing those added info

Comment: No need in more info. This is trivial cross-domain tracking from GA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your [cross-domain tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10071811?hl=en) if you don't need it. These parameters help the destination site reuse your site's google client and session ids.

This usually makes sense only when both sites track users in the same GA property.